# Access resource attributes from within Rails Formbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formbuilder

I'm trying to add tooltips to read-only inputs that might not always be wide enough to show the full content. The tooltips will be used to show the full content when the user hovers over the input.

The problem is that I cannot seem to access the resource attributes in the form builder paramaters section. I'm trying to make the value of the input the title. See the following code:

```
= f.fields_for :invoice_items, @invoice.invoice_items do |item|
   %tr
      %td
         = item.text_field :code, :title => item.name, :rel=>'tooltip', :class => 'uneditable-input span1', :readonly=>'true
```

Raises:

```
undefined method `name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fea1e86f8e8>
```

Now with that we can see that item isn't actually the resource, but the form builder class. How can I access the original resource from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
= f.fields_for :invoice_items, @invoice.invoice_items do |item|
   %tr
      %td
         = item.text_field :code, :title => item.object.name, :rel=>'tooltip', :class => 'uneditable-input span1', :readonly=>'true
```

You might need to take out the second parameter, the

```
@invoice.invoice_items
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, item.object.name did the trick. How did you know this, if I may ask? @invoice.invoice_items is needed however as it's in a belongs_to/has_many relationship to the invoice.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it worked. Regarding how I knew it, I noticed an example of it in the documentation for one-to-many relationships in fields_for on the [rails api site](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <%= person_form.fields_for :projects do |project_fields| %>
    <% if project_fields.object.active? %>
      Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>